# Gnuplot: Where is my mistake?

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot, geogebra

I would like to plot a function. But the results from `gnuplottex` and `gegogebra` are different. Where is the mistake?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\newcommand*\GnuplotDefs{
    set samples 50;
    dexp(x,l) = l * exp(-l*x);
    dweibull(x,a,b) = (a/b) * ((x/b)**(a-1)) * exp(-(x/b)**a);
    kexpweibull(x,l,a,b,p) =  p * dexp(x,l) + (1-p) * dweibull(x,a,b);
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    ymin=0,
    ymax=0.1,
    no markers,
    smooth,
    every axis plot post/.append style={very thick},
    xlabel={x},
    ylabel={probability density},
    ]
    \addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot] {
        \GnuplotDefs
        plot [x = 0:25] kexpweibull(x,0.2,5,15,0.2);
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about gnuplot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is **off topic**, as it concerns `gnuplot` and not `LaTeX`.

But to answer your question:

The problem is, that the result of `(a/b)` in

```
dweibull(x,a,b) = (a/b) * ((x/b)**(a-1)) * exp(-(x/b)**a);
```

is `0`, if `a=5` and `b=15`, because gnuplot assumes those to be integers. In order to make it work, you just have to use:

```
plot [x = 0:25] kexpweibull(x,0.2,5.0,15.0,0.2);
```

instead of

```
plot [x = 0:25] kexpweibull(x,0.2,5,15,0.2);
```

so `a=5.0` and `b=15.0` are interpreted as floats (or doubles) and not integers.

Here is a sample output:

[image]